# TFS-Board: Make field mandatory when moved to done column in kanban board

Tags: tfs, storyboard, project-template, kanban

We have a customized workflow in TFS 2017 and want to make a field mandatory (REQUIRED) when the work item is pulled to the kanban done column (state will not change!).
As far as I know only state changes may get REQUIRED rules.

I tried this but it does not work:

```
<FIELD name="AcceptanceCriteria" refname="Whiteduck.Scrumban.AcceptanceCriteria" type="HTML">
  <HELPTEXT>What criterias have to be fulfilled (what, how, restrictions, etc.).</HELPTEXT>
  <WHEN field="System.BoardColumnDone" value="true">
    <REQUIRED />
  </WHEN>
</FIELD>
```

For state changes this had worked:

```
<TRANSITION from="Analyze" to="Test">
  <REASONS>
    <DEFAULTREASON value="Test" />
  </REASONS>
  <FIELDS>
    ...
    <FIELD refname="Whiteduck.Scrumban.AcceptanceCriteria">
      <REQUIRED />
    </FIELD>
  </FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
```

*Any chances to apply a rule on a kanban done pull?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To  make a field  mandatory in a work item  you just need to  add the REQUIRED rule for your field. It's not related to states changes only.

> **REQUIRED**
>
> Requires a user to specify a value for the field. Users cannot save a
>   work item until they have assigned values to all required fields.

More details please refer this tutorial-- [Require, read-only, and restrict values](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/apply-rule-work-item-field#require-read-only-and-restrict-values)

> You can specify these rules to **take affect** during **a workflow
>   transition** or as child elements within a FIELD (Global workflow)
>   element.

So this will not work when the work item is pulled to the kanban done column without a transition. Your requirement could not be achieved for now.

Comment: Summarized: Not possible at the moment because rules only take effect on transitions between states and kanban doing/done is no state change. 
WorkAround: Add a new state "DevelopDone" and apply a rule on that state.